# Resizing plots in the Julia kernel for Jupyter notebooks

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook, vega, ijulia-notebook

I want to know if there is any way that I can specify the size of the inline-plots in Jupyter. At the moment, I use Vega library and width and height don't work. There is any workaround.

Comment: what backend are you using for plotting? PyPlot? GR? This question also applies if you are using Plots.jl since Plots.jl also offers backend selection possibility.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Vega, though I think there is an environmental variable for ijulia. Using Plots, you can just `default(size = (1000, 300))`.

Comment: Thx but that doesn't work with me even with Plots library.

Comment: That's weird though

Comment: this seems to work on Juliabox, but doesn't work offline

Answer (score 3):

To change the plot size using Vega.jl within Jupyter Notebook, you modify the `width` and `height` properties:

```
using Vega

#defaults are width = 450 and height = 450
b = barplot(x = [1,2,3], y = [1,2,3]) 

#change to whatever values you want
b.width = 200
b.height = 50

#re-render
b
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work with Plots.jl:

```
using Plots
plot(1:5, size=(1000,1000))
```